# Reset the filter (Date Range) of a DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have implemented version 1.13.1 of the DataTable. Which I have the filter by date range, and I have created two buttons, one to proceed with the filter, and the other to reset it.

[Date Range Filter Datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables.html)

What I want is that when I press my reset button, the filter is removed from the table, and from the fields.

I have inserted `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();` at the top of the method to clean the filter, but it only works perfect the first time, then it doesn't even filter anymore.

```
 <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Desde el:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="min" name="min">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hasta el:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="max" name="max">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <button id="filtrar_fecha">Filtrar</button>
                    <button id="reset_filtrar_fecha">Resetear</button>
                </td>                
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

```
var minDate, maxDate;

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var min = minDate.val();
        var max = maxDate.val();
        var date = new Date( data[5] );
 
        if (
            ( min === null && max === null ) ||
            ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
            ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
            ( min <= date   && date <= max )
        ) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
);
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
        format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
    });
    maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
        format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
    });
 
 
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    
    $("#filtrar_fecha").click(function() {        
        table.draw();
    });

    $("#reset_filtrar_fecha").click(function() {        
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();        
        $("#min").val("");
        $("#max").val("");
        table.columns().search("").draw(); 
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Looking for a solution, it seems that I found it, but I am presented with another problem.

Apparently the problem of resetting the filter works, but when I apply the filter to see that everything works correctly, it shows me incorrect results (not in the first results, but in the 5th, etc.)

Is it okay this way that I try to solve the problem?

```
var minDate, maxDate;
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Create date inputs
    minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
        format: 'DD / MM / YYYY'
    });
    maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
        format: 'DD / MM / YYYY'
    });
 
    // DataTables initialisation
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    $("#filtrar_fecha").click(function() {

       if ( $("#min").val() !== "" || $("#max").val() !== "") {

            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
                    var min = minDate.val();
                    var max = maxDate.val();
                    var date = new Date( data[5] );
             
                    if (
                        ( min === null && max === null ) ||
                        ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
                        ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
                        ( min <= date   && date <= max )
                    ) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            );

            table.draw();
        }
    });

    $("#reset_filtrar_fecha").click(function() {
        $("#min, #max").val("");
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.search = [];
        table.draw(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Don't use `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();`. That removes the filter _function_ from the array of filter functions used by DataTables. (It's the opposite of the `push` command, where your filter is added to the array of DataTables filter functions.) You want to keep the function - but just reset the values. So, what happens if you remove that one line from your code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nothing happens. it only stays in the result of the applied filter.

Comment: I have **updated** the information in the question, in case it can help.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

For future visitors to this answer, I think the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74766814/12567365) is much better than mine.

---

There are 2 changes needed:

1. Don't use `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();`

That removes the filter function from the array of filter functions used by DataTables. (It's the opposite of the push command, where your filter is added to the array of DataTables filter functions.) You want to keep the function - but just reset the values.

2. You need to re-initialize `minDate` and `maxDate`.

You can repeat the same code as you already have for that - or, better, place it in a function and call the function.

Here is a demo:

```js
var minDate, maxDate;

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var min = minDate.val();
    var max = maxDate.val();
    var date = new Date(data[4]);

    if (
      (min === null && max === null) ||
      (min === null && date <= max) ||
      (min <= date && max === null) ||
      (min <= date && date <= max)
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);

function initializeMinMax() {
  minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
    format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
  });
  maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
    format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  initializeMinMax();


  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $("#filtrar_fecha").click(function() {

    table.draw();
  });

  $("#reset_filtrar_fecha").click(function() {
    //$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
    $("#min").val('');
    $("#max").val('');
    initializeMinMax();
    table.draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.2.0/js/dataTables.dateTime.min.js"></script>


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/datetime/1.2.0/css/dataTables.dateTime.min.css">


</head>

<body>

  <div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Desde el:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="min" name="min">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Hasta el:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" id="max" name="max">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button id="filtrar_fecha">Filtrar</button>
            <button id="reset_filtrar_fecha">Resetear</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <br><br>


    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office in Country</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior "Technical" Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Sonya Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Donna Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

---

Note: My test data requires me to use this:

```
var date = new Date(data[4]);
```

In your code, it looks as if the date data is in `data[5]` (column index 5) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The filter problem seems solved. But this causes a problem with the date picker. The first time a date is selected and the filter button is pressed, it works. Then proceed to press the reset button and it works too. But, the second time that another date is selected, the calendar returns to the initial state, and even worse, if the same date is selected as the second time, the calendar seems locked and does not close. :(

Comment: I'm not able to see the calendar becoming locked, or returning to its initial state unexpectedly, in the way you describe - but I do see that you need to click outside of the calendar to close it. I don' know why that is happening (needing to click outside to close it).

Comment: You may get an answer for that specific issue if you ask a new, separate question. I don't see anything obvious which is causing this.

Comment: [**Here**](https://i.ibb.co/yyPPbf3/GIF.gif) I leave a demonstration of what I mean. I hope it helps to understand the problem.

Comment: The problem may be caused by the function `initializeMinMax()` (which contains the calendar inside the Inputs) being called twice.

Comment: Yes - that demo is showing what I mentioned - you have to _click outside the calendar_. I did not understand "_being called twice_" - each calendar is initialized one on page reload, then reset once when the "reset" button is clicked. My suggestion is the same as above: You can ask a new specific question about this, so it will be seen by a wider audience. But I cannot recreate your problem about the calendar freezing - it does not freeze. And I cannot recreate your problem about the calendar resetting itself, either. Definitely ask a new question. Sorry, I am not able to help with this.